# An annotation processor exception

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, maven, netbeans-7

When i build project using maven and netbeans i got this exception : "java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for org.jaxen.FunctionContext not found".

In [this](http://forums.netbeans.org/topic51161.html) article people said that solution is to disable annotation processing in NB, but i don't have this checkbox into the build settings of my project.
[image]
Maybe someone knows how to solve this problem or how to disable annotation processing

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As for disabling annotations processing part, it's controlled by `-proc:none` option for javac; thus you can set

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <proc>none</proc>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: org.jaxen.FunctionContext is an annotation that java compiler is attempting to process (http://hannesdorfmann.com/annotation-processing/annotationprocessing101 might shed some light) unless instructed to skip processing. In fact, this is might be a dependency that just needs to be satisfied, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/19141989/657619 .

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with this problem again and found other solution. I just remove "target" folder of my project and project was compiled successfully

Answer (score 0):

If you disable annotations process maybe your project is not going to run on final deploy destination, the best way to solve the problem is downloading the jaxen  library at

http://jaxen.codehaus.org/releases.html

And then import jaxen-*.jar into your project.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exception pop up when using poi and poi-ooxml dependencies. The root cause was that I had a private member of type XSSFCellStyle in one of my classes. Changing the type to CellStyle made this compile time exception go away.